# OpenCL: querying the GPU for a set of results with an unknown size

Tags: buffer, gpu, opencl, knn

I've written a spatial hashmap using openCL for doing distance queries between points in a set. The idea is for each point in the set, I want to find all other points in the set within a certain radius.

Right now I do the search in two passes: in the first pass I find all the neighboring points for each query point and return the total number of results back to the CPU (as a single, atomically-incremented integer), then I construct a buffer of that size, and do the search again in a second pass, this time adding neighbors to the buffer which is then sent back to the CPU for processing. Using this method, the buffer is guaranteed to be exactly the size of the resulting point size, but since this technique performs the full search query in two passes, it's taking up to twice as long as a hypothetical ideal solution.

Another solution might be to construct a buffer that is guaranteed to be able to hold the maximum number of results, even if it is never actually filled. But in situations where points are very spread out, this could mean I construct a buffer with enough space to hold millions of entries, which only ends up holding a few (or even none)...that seems horribly inefficient.

Are there any other methods for doing this kind of thing? Or is the two pass solution the best solution?

Comment: If you create a buffer in device memory that is guaranteed to be large enough to hold the result, but only copy as much data as was actually written to the buffer back to the host, the only overhead is in temporarily over-allocating device memory (VRAM, …). Assuming you're not getting near your device's limit, this shouldn't be a problem. Have you done any measurements on the different options?

Comment: Another option would be to allocate enough for some percentage of cases (80%, 90%, 95%, 99%, etc. - profile what works best), fill that to the extent possible, and if it's exceeded, fall back to a second pass.

Comment: Yet another option if you need to get through multiple data sets: create a buffer that is large enough for N% of the maximum possible result size, then only kick off work items for N% of the problem set. Do this for the first N% of multiple problem sets in parallel, then for each problem set, run the next N% of the problem, etc. and build up your results incrementally.

Comment: Which of these is best will depend on memory access patterns, problem sizes, statistical distribution of your data, the OpenCL platform (hardware + driver), etc…

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Filling a modest buffer and falling back to a second pass if needed seems like an interesting solution...I'll do some testing to see if I can squeeze out extra performance using that technique.